# Use of \thedots@ doesn't match its definition. Problem with the French package

Tags: babel, french, kaobook

I have a fairly complicated document in English, typeset using kaobook.

For my abstract I need to add French and adding `french` to the line
`\usepackage[main=english, ngerman, french]{babel}`
results in the above error. The line in question with the error is

```
\begin{equation}
\vb{A} = \vb{L}^{(1)} \vb{L}^{(2)} \dots \vb{L}^{(r)} \vb{\tilde{A}}^{(r)} \vb{R}^{(r)} \dots \vb{R}^{(2)} \vb{R}^{(1)}
\end{equation}
```

Unfortunately, I was unable to reproduce the error in a MWE.. Help is very much appreciated!

EDIT: MWE added

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[main=english, ngerman, french]{babel}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{bm}

\renewcommand{\vb}[1]{\bm{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage*}{french}
La physique des ondes apparaît dans la nature entre autres sous forme d’ondes électromagnétiques, d’ondes sonores ou encore d’ondes 
\end{otherlanguage*}
  
\begin{equation}
  \vb{L}^{(1)} \vb{L}^{(2)} \dots \vb{L}^{(r)}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I realised that and went back.. I realised the problem were the surrounding bold symbols. I posted the MWE

Comment: sorry, couldn't keep up with your speed :D

Comment: oi and the error shows `\bm`, that's one of mine... :-)

Comment: It seems I came to the right place then! :)

Comment: @campa Brexit ?

Comment: Do you really need `physics`? I don't recommend using it: it has a clumsy interface and makes some bad typographic decisions (of course, this is my opinion). Without it the example runs fine; on the other hand, loading `amsmath` breaks again.

Comment: I agree with most of that.. I just got used to it during my undergrad. It is useful mostly due to its matrix definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>French and/or physics</strike> `amsmath` seem to be upsetting `bm`.

However without delving too deeply in to why you can protect `\bm` with extra braces, you get no error from

```
\renewcommand{\vb}[1]{{\bm{#1}}}
```

A more permanent fix could be made in `amsmath` by changing one instance of `\boldsymbol` to `##1`

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\makeatletter
\def\mdots@@{\gdef\thedots@{\dotso@}%
 \ifx\@let@token\boldsymbol
%   \gdef\thedots@\boldsymbol{\boldsymboldots@}%
   \gdef\thedots@##1{\boldsymboldots@}%
 \else
   \ifx,\@let@token \gdef\thedots@{\dotsc}%
   \else
     \ifx\not\@let@token
       \gdef\thedots@{\dotsb@}%
     \else
       \keybin@
       \ifgtest@ % if \keybin@ test
         \gdef\thedots@{\dotsb@}%
       \else
         \xdef\meaning@{\meaning\@let@token. .........}%
         \xdef\meaning@@{\@xp\striplong@\meaning@\relax\meaning@}%
         \@xp\math@\meaning@\math@
         \ifgtest@ % if \mathxxx test
           \@xp\mathch@\meaning@\mathch@
           \ifgtest@ % if \mathchar
             \@xp\getmathch@\meaning@\getmathch@
           \fi % end if \mathchar
         \else  % \not \mathxxx
             \@xp\Umathch@\meaning@"0"\Umathch@
             \ifgtest@ % if \Umathchar
             \else % else not \Umathcar
           \@xp\macro@\meaning@@\macro@
           \ifgtest@ % if macro test
             \@xp\not@\meaning@\not@
             \ifgtest@ % if macro starts \not test
               \gdef\thedots@{\dotsb@}%
             \else% else not \not
               \@xp\DOTS@\meaning@\DOTS@
               \ifgtest@ % \if DOTS
                 \ifcase\number\DOTSCASE@ %ifcase dots
                   \gdef\thedots@{\dotsb@}%
                 \or\gdef\thedots@{\dotsi}\else
                 \fi % endifcase dots
               \else % not macro starts \DOTS
                 \@xp\math@\meaning@\math@
                 \ifgtest@ % \if macro starts \mathxxxx
                   \@xp\mathbin@\meaning@\mathbin@
                   \ifgtest@ % if macro starts \mathbin
                     \gdef\thedots@{\dotsb@}%
                   \else % not macro starting \mathbin
                     \@xp\mathrel@\meaning@\mathrel@
                     \ifgtest@ % if macro starts \mathrel
                       \gdef\thedots@{\dotsb@}%
                     \fi % endif macro starts \mathrel (no else)
                   \fi % endif macro starts \mathbin
                 \fi % endif macro starts with \mathxxx (no else)
               \fi % endif macro starts \DOTS else
             \fi % end macro  starting \not \ifgtest@ test (no else)
             \else
               \@xp\thecharacter@\meaning@\thecharacter@
             \fi % end macro \ifgtest@ test (no else)
           \fi % end if \Umathchar test
         \fi % end \math@   \ifgtest@
       \fi % end \keybin@ \ifgtest@ test (no else)
     \fi % end if \not (no else)
   \fi % end if comma (no else)
 \fi % end if boldsymbol (no else)
 \thedots@}
\makeatother
\begin{document}



$\dots 1$ $\dots\bm{1}$

$1 + \dots + 5$ $1\bm{+}  \dots\bm{+} 5$

\end{document}
``
```

Comment: Thank you, very much appreciated! Don't upset the French with Physics or bold Maths ;)

Comment: I'm tracking it down and it's not about `physics`. `amsmath` is enough. The expansion of `\dots` comes to the branch where it expects a `\boldsymbol` following it, which then fails with the given error.

Comment: @campa yes thanks I was going to look at the weekend, if you track down anything I should do in bm, ping me here:-)

Comment: Also `\let\vb\bm`

Answer (score 3):

I recommend not using `physics`. Anyway, it is not directly related to `physics`, but it's an interaction with `amsmath`.

Here's a more minimal example:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\vb}[1]{\bm{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\vb{L}\dots\vb{L}$

\end{document}
```

You can work around the issue by using `\NewCommandCopy` (or `\RenewCommandCopy` if you insist in using `physics`):

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\NewCommandCopy{\vb}{\bm}

\begin{document}

$\vb{L}\dots\vb{L}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: french redefines \dots and I think they messed up the \expandafter there (\@xp). In the amsmath definition is catches the \else and \fi, but here it affects the following command.

Comment: Oh no, actually `\dots\bm{L}` breaks without french.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yeah, `bm` does `\let\boldsymbol\bm` so the `\ifx` performed by `\mdots@@` returns true, but the following expansion of `\thedots@` finds `\bm` and not `\boldsymbol` as expected. Unhappy definitions colliding... but I also think the the `\@xp` in `french` is wrong.

Comment: @campa yes I just put a possible amsmath fix in my answer

Comment: Indeed the \@xp in babel-french is wrong. I'll remove it asap.

Comment: @everyone Thanks a lot for the helpful answers. I will keep a mental note for the future to avoid physics and write my own macros. It's very convenient though as a starting point...